# How do I can Iterate this structure from ArrayList

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist

I am pretty new on Java, and I'm wondering how to iterate this ArrayList

```
[
    [{ID_CLIENTE=1}, {CODIGO=001}, {NOMBRES=John}, {STA=1}], 
    [{ID_CLIENTE=2}, {CODIGO=003}, {NOMBRES=Laura },  {STA=1}]
]
```

this is an arraylist that contains a record on each row, and inside there is a value/pair for the column name and value, and draw only the selected columns on the column array. 
This is my Java Code:

```
String columns = request.getParameter("columns");
String[] cols =  columns.split(",");
List<ArrayList<String>> mant =  mantDao.getAllMant(); // this return the arraylist shown above

    for(ArrayList<String> row: mant){
          //IF it is ON cols array 
          // response.getWriter().write("<tr>td>"+row.get(index) +"</td>"....); <-- BAD CODE    

    }
```

Any help will be really apprecciated. I'm stuck on this for while.

EDIT:
this is the getAllMant() function

```
public List getAllMant() {        
    ArrayList mant = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(this.query);

        campos = this.getCampos();
            while (rs.next()) {
        ArrayList row = new ArrayList<>();
        for(List<String> campo: campos){
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            String valueField = "";
            if( Arrays.asList(INTS).contains(Integer.parseInt(campo.get(1)) ) ){
            valueField = String.valueOf(rs.getInt(campo.get(0)));
            }else if( Arrays.asList(NUMBERS).contains(Integer.parseInt( campo.get(1)) ) ){
            valueField = String.valueOf(rs.getLong(campo.get(0)));
            }else if( Arrays.asList(VARCHAR).contains(Integer.parseInt( campo.get(1)) ) ){
            valueField = rs.getString(campo.get(0)) ;
            }else if( Arrays.asList(DATES).contains(Integer.parseInt( campo.get(1)) ) ){
            if(rs.getDate(campo.get(0)) !=null){
                valueField = rs.getDate(campo.get(0)).toString();
            }else{
                valueField = "";
            }
            }
            lhm.put(campo.get(0),valueField);
            row.add(lhm);
        }
        mant.add(row);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mant;
    }
```

regards

Comment: it looks like JSON ya?

Comment: aint JSON, does not pass jsonlint.com

Comment: does it successfully create a `List<ArrayList<String>> mant`?

Comment: what is return type of **getAllMant()** api, are you sure it is **List<ArrayList<String>>**

Comment: Thank you.. I will edit my post to show you the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense to replace the `List<ArrayList<String>>` with a `List<Map<String,String>>`, since `Map` is better suited for storage of key/value pairs.

Then your code could look like this :

```
for(Map<String,String> row: mant){
      String id = row.get("ID_CLIENTE"); // fetch a value by its key
}
```

Looking at the additional code you posted, it seems you are creating an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, but you try to put a `LinkedHashMap<String,String>` in the inner list. This makes no sense, and won't work.
You should replace the inner List with a Map :

```
public List getAllMant() 
{        
    ArrayList<Map<String,String>> mant = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(this.query);

        campos = this.getCampos();
        while (rs.next()) {
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            for(List<String> campo: campos){            
                String valueField = "";
                if( Arrays.asList(INTS).contains(Integer.parseInt(campo.get(1)) ) ){
                    valueField = String.valueOf(rs.getInt(campo.get(0)));
                } else if( Arrays.asList(NUMBERS).contains(Integer.parseInt( campo.get(1)) ) ){
                    valueField = String.valueOf(rs.getLong(campo.get(0)));
                } else if( Arrays.asList(VARCHAR).contains(Integer.parseInt( campo.get(1)) ) ){
                    valueField = rs.getString(campo.get(0)) ;
                } else if( Arrays.asList(DATES).contains(Integer.parseInt( campo.get(1)) ) ){
                    if(rs.getDate(campo.get(0)) !=null){
                        valueField = rs.getDate(campo.get(0)).toString();
                    } else{
                        valueField = "";
                    }
                }
                row.put(campo.get(0),valueField);
            }
            mant.add(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mant;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post, maybe it will be useful to show you the function. I can't figured out yet.